# Issues with 960gs and Internet Explorer on my blog

Tags: css, layout, 960.gs

I have put up a new blog which uses Toto with Rails 3 and it is working perfectly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. The problem is that Internet Explorer 7 and 8 don't render the pages right. I'm using 960gs grid system and a very simple CSS markup.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand why 960gs is not working as well as the header of the site not using proper CSS in IE while other browsers are working properly

http://vova.org

**Edit 1**: If I use IE Developer Tool and look at the HTML, I see that it is not parsed well, for example:

```
</header/>
<section/>
```

Comment: Try to add a reset css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: I tried Eric Meyer's CSS reset and it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the HTML5 shim for IE support.  Simply put this in your html `<head>`.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
....
```

You can read up on the HTML5 shim and its history here: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I also +1 everyone else since the answers are very similar.

Answer (score 2):

To get HTML5 Elements working in older versions of Internet Explorer, you have to use a [HTML5 enabling script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/).

For further infos, see here: [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html).

Answer (score 1):

You use HTML5, its not supported by IE7. Tags like `header`, `section`, `article` are HTML5 tags.
use `div` tags instead to avoid the problem or just ignore IE7 users, but show them a message why they shouldn't use IE7